# How to remove ghost languages

Tags: settings, language-support, user-profile

I have two ghost languages to select for the keyboard settings, altough they do not appear at the text entry settings panel (See the `m17n*` options on the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Wkf.png)).

They only appear with my user, and not with any other user on the system.

Does anyone knows how can I remove them?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: The output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` is

```
[('ibus', 'm17n:he:kbd'), ('ibus', 'm17n:en:ispell'), ('xkb', 'il'), ('xkb', 'us')]
```

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply start the command below

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'il'), ('xkb', 'us')]"
```

to correct the values and check with

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
```

Comment: Thank you, is it permanent, or I need to call it on every reboot?

Comment: That should be permanent. Give me a comment if not.